# What is Apple warning against in ARC documentation caveat about pass by reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

In Apple's documentation about ARC, they make a point of spelling out a problematic scenario in which ARC will generate a boilerplate temporary variable behind the scenes. Search on "The compiler therefore rewrites":

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

The gist of the warning seems to be that because the stack-based variable is "strong" and the by-reference parameter to the called method (performOperationWithError:) is autoreleasing, ARC will generate a temporary local variable to serve the memory management needs of the autoreleasing variable. But because the temporary variable is assigned to the strong variable in the boilerplate example, it seems as though from a client's point of view there is no risk.

What exactly is the documentation taking pains to warn us about here? What is the risk as either a client or as an implementor of a method that may be called in this way (with an autoreleased, return-by-value parameter)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's only a warning about less than ideal performance. In the rewritten code, the NSError pointed to by "tmp" comes back autoreleased, is retained when assigned to "error", and then is released again when "error" goes out of scope.

If you change the declaration in the original code to:
NSError __autoreleasing *error;

If you do this, there is no assignment to a temp, and that implicit retain and then release no longer occurs. (The NSError object itself is still valid for exactly as long as it was before, since it is still in the autorelease pool.) So the documentation is warning you that if you use the "wrong" variable qualifier that it can cause extra retain count munging that wouldn't otherwise be required.

Also note that with either version of the code: Because the variable in question is passed by reference and isn't the return value from -performOperationWithError:, there isn't the opportunity to do the magic stack walking trick that ARC can do to save the object from going into the autorelease pool in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! My main cause for concern was the phrasing in the docs "You also need to take care with objects passed by reference." It would have helped a lot if they said why. It seems like your explanation is likely the main consideration to concern oneself with.

Answer (score 9):

I think it’s to prevent confusion if you start looking at the values passed into the method. In their example, if I set a breakpoint on the line that calls `[myObject performOperationWithError:&tmp];` and type `p error`, I’ll see the address of it. But if I step into `-performOperationWithError:` and type `p error`, I’ll get a *different* value—inside the method, `error` points to that temporary value.

I can see a situation where some poor sap is trying to debug something tricky with ARC where the pointer changing as it gets passed into the method would be an extremely confusing red herring.

Answer (score 5):

My guess: If you made assumptions about the memory referenced by the output parameter, e.g indexing off the pointer, you might be surprised.

Comment: That too! In general, mixing ARC and pointer arithmetic for Objective-C objects should be done with ample care and only as a last resort.

Comment: Yep, interesting stuff. I think they should phrase it more as informational instead of introducing it "You also need to take care with objects"

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it has anything to do with the client. It looks like a reference to the same issue addressed in the WWDC 2013 video on memory issues: If you yourself *implement* a method that takes an autoreleasing indirection parameter (such as an `NSError**`), and if you create an autorelease pool block inside that method, do not assign to the NSError from inside the autorelease pool block. Instead, assign to a local variable, and then assign from the local to the NSError outside the autorelease pool block.

Comment: But that's just a guess. In any case watch the video and see for yourself whether you think it's related. You might do well, if you don't get a satisfactory answer here, to ask on the cocoa-dev list, where Greg Parker himself is likely to pop up with a straight-from-the-horse's-mouth answer. That is where I've always gotten my best info on this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting nuance and I wish they had mentioned it more overtly in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to me that it's less of a warning about this behavior than a description of what the compiler does in this case and why you can pass the address of a strong local error reference to a method that is declared as wanting an __autoreleasing reference and not trigger a complaint.

You generally want an API to use __autoreleasing on such a parameter in case it is being used by either ARC or non-ARC code, as in non-ARC code it would be unusual to have to release such an output parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Troy! Sounds like I don't have much to worry about. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 4):

The Apple documentation is referring to a compiler **misfeature** that will synthesize a temporary variable for you to deal with the conversion between __block and __autoreleasing. Sadly, this doesn't solve very many problems *and* it produces potentially disasterous unexpected results.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    __block id value = @"initial value";
    void (^block)(id *outValue) = ^(id *outValue){
        value = @"hello";
    };
    block(&value);
    NSLog(@"value = %@", value);
    return 0;
}
```

With ARC, this reports:

```
2013-04-24 13:55:35.814 block-local-address[28013:707] value = initial value
```

but with MRR:

```
2013-04-24 13:57:26.058 block-local-address[28046:707] value = hello
```

This very often comes up when using NSFileCoordinator, causing you to lose the resulting NSError!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/tmp/foo"];
    NSFileCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];

    __block NSError *error;
    [coordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:fileURL options:0 error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL){
        NSDictionary *userInfo = @{
            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Testing bubbling an error out from a file coordination block."
        };
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain code:ENOSYS userInfo:userInfo];
    }];

    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}
```

When compiled with ARC, this results in a nil error!

This has been written up as [a bug at llvm.org](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15649#add_comment) for a while, though I just changed the title to make it more clear that I'm suggesting the feature be ripped out. Also attached to that bug is a patch to add a new flag `-fno-objc-arc-writeback` to disable the feature).

Comment: I should also note that if you tag these variables as `__autoreleasing`, the compiler will correctly warn about using it both as `__autoreleasing` and `_block`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Tim. I'm glad to know the vagueness of the documentation may reflect the vagueness of the behavior's justification!